# Performing a process in the background while recording with a video stream

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ocr

I need to do something in my iPhone project is to call some methods while recording a video with a video streaming.
The main idea of the project is to record a text with live camera and while recording I should show the results once recording in another view above the camera.

I already performed the process that can recognise the text, All I need is to call it while recording not after taking a photo.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send your process to the background thread before you start recording.

It sounds like recording is taking up your main thread so you don't see the second process begin until after recording has ended.

Sample Code:

```
//do something before sending to background
[self setupUI];

//send code to background
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    // backgroung processing
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com"]]];

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // background processing complete
        button.image = btnImage;
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem that I didn't know how to send the process to the background process,,I was asking about how to di this ???